# Find number of matching elements in grouped tibble

Tags: group-by, matching

I have a tibble

```
set.seed = 100
tb = tibble(
  gp = rep(letters[1:3],each = 5),
  val = sample(c(1:10),size = 15, replace = T)
)
```

I want to know how many times each value of `val` occurs within each group, `gp`. I tried the following:

```
tb_match = tb %>%
  group_by(gp) %>%
  group_modify(
    {
      ~
        .x %>%
        mutate(n_match = sum(val %in% .x$val))
    }
  )
```

The idea behind my attempted solution is that values that have an exact match should have a sum(val %in% val) of >1. for example if I want to know how many matching values are in the vector `c(1,2,3)`, I would check the vector against each value in the vector

```
sum(c(1,2,3) %in% 1)
sum(c(1,2,3) %in% 2)
sum(c(1,2,3) %in% 3)
```

returns no values greater than 1, because there are no matching values, but

```
sum(c(1,1,3) %in% 1)
sum(c(1,1,3) %in% 1)
sum(c(1,1,3) %in% 3)
```

returns two values of 2 because there is a single match. I'm attempting to perform this kind of procedure across groups, but I need to be able to specify all the values in the group *and* each individual value in the group and I don't know how to do that.

I think the problem I'm having is that I don't know how to specify the individual row of val versus the whole grouped column. So it's returning the fact that all 5 values do occur in the grouped column. I figure there is probably a way to do this, or else I'm barking up the complete wrong tree on how to find matching values within groups.

This feels like it's probably something simple and obvious but after reading the documentation, no solution is jumping out at me. Any help would be appreciated.

I *could* do this with some nested for loops but my real dataset is quite large and I'm trying to avoid the speed hit from for loops.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the solution. For anyone else who needs a similar task, the `rowwise()` dplyr function is what's needed, plus a slight tweaking of my mutate function:

```
tb_match = tb %>%
  group_by(gp) %>%
  group_modify(
    {
      ~
        .x %>%
        rowwise() %>%
        mutate(n_match = sum(.$val %in% val))
    }
  )
```